# Duplicates links in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

Good morning world

I'm new to python and trying out things. I'm trying to remove duplicate links from the below run.
currently their are 253 links that were retrieved. Can someone please help me with this?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv

page = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"

r = requests.get(page)

raw_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all("a")

print ('Number of links retrieved: ', len (links))
```

Comment: `links = set(links)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to a set and it will remove duplicates:

```
links = set(soup.find_all("a"))

out:
Number of links retrieved:  244
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. you guys are the best can't wait to learn this stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

`set` will not care about the sort order.

Therefor i used a `list` with cleaning the `href` correctly.

Now the `len` is `123`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

links = []
for item in soup.findAll("a", href=True):
    item = item.get("href")
    if item.startswith("h"):
        pass
    else:
        item = f"https://www.census.gov/{item}"
    if item not in links:
        links.append(item)
        print(item)


print(len(links))
```

Output:

```
https://www.census.gov/#content
https://www.census.gov/en.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/age-and-sex.html
https://www.census.gov/businessandeconomy
https://www.census.gov/topics/education.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/preparedness.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/employment.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/families.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/migration.html
https://www.census.gov/geo
https://www.census.gov/topics/health.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/hispanic-origin.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/housing.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/income-poverty.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/international-trade.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/population-estimates.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/population/race.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/research.html
https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector/voting.html
https://www.census.gov/about/index.html
https://www.census.gov/data
https://www.census.gov/academy
https://www.census.gov/about/what/admin-data.html
https://www.census.gov/data/data-tools.html
https://www.census.gov/developers/
https://www.census.gov/data/experimental-data-products.html
https://www.census.gov/data/related-sites.html
https://www.census.gov/data/software.html
https://www.census.gov/data/tables.html
https://www.census.gov/data/training-workshops.html
https://www.census.gov/library/visualizations.html
https://www.census.gov/library.html
https://www.census.gov/AmericaCounts
https://www.census.gov/library/audio.html
https://www.census.gov/library/fact-sheets.html
https://www.census.gov/library/photos.html
https://www.census.gov/library/publications.html
https://www.census.gov/library/video.html
https://www.census.gov/library/working-papers.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/are-you-in-a-survey.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/2020census-redirect.html
https://www.census.gov/2020census
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/abs.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/asm.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/cog.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/cbp.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps.html
https://www.census.gov/EconomicCensus
https://www.census.gov/internationalprograms
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/metro-micro.html
https://www.census.gov/popest
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popproj.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/susb.html
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sbo.html
https://www.census.gov/sipp/
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/surveys-programs.html
https://www.census.gov/newsroom.html
https://www.census.gov/partners
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sis.html
https://www.census.gov/NAICS
https://www.census.gov/library/reference/code-lists/schedule/b.html
https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/Geocoding-services.html
https://www.census.gov/about-us
https://www.census.gov/about/who.html
https://www.census.gov/about/what.html
https://www.census.gov/about/business-opportunities.html
https://www.census.gov/careers
https://www.census.gov/fieldjobs
https://www.census.gov/about/history.html
https://www.census.gov/about/policies.html
https://www.census.gov/privacy
https://www.census.gov/regions
https://www.census.gov/about/contact-us/staff-finder.html
https://www.census.gov/about/contact-us.html
https://www.census.gov/about/faqs.html
https://www.commerce.gov/
https://www.census.gov//en.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys.html
https://www.census.gov//popest
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/about.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/data.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/geographies.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/guidance.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/guidance-geographies.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/library.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/news.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/technical-documentation.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/data/tables.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/about/schedule.html
https://www.census.gov//newsroom/press-releases/2019/popest-nation.html
https://www.census.gov//newsroom/press-releases/2019/popest-nation/popest-nation-spanish.html
https://www.census.gov//newsroom/press-releases/2019/new-years-2020.html
https://www.census.gov//data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/pre-1980-national.html
https://www.census.gov//data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/pre-1980-state.html
https://www.census.gov//data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/pre-1980-county.html
https://www.census.gov//library/publications/2015/demo/p25-1142.html
https://www.census.gov//library/publications/2010/demo/p25-1139.html
https://www.census.gov//library/publications/2010/demo/p25-1138.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/library/publications.html
https://www.census.gov//library/visualizations/2020/comm/superbowl.html
https://www.census.gov//library/visualizations/2019/comm/slower-growth-nations-pop.html
https://www.census.gov//library/visualizations/2019/comm/happy-new-year-2020.html
https://www.census.gov//programs-surveys/popest/library/visualizations.html
https://www.census.gov/#
https://www.census.gov/#uscb-nav-skip-header
https://www.census.gov/newsroom/blogs.html
https://www.census.gov/newsroom/stories.html
https://www.facebook.com/uscensusbureau
https://twitter.com/uscensusbureau
https://www.linkedin.com/company/us-census-bureau
https://www.youtube.com/user/uscensusbureau
https://www.instagram.com/uscensusbureau/
https://www.census.gov/quality/
https://www.census.gov/datalinkage
https://www.census.gov/about/policies/privacy/privacy-policy.html#accessibility
https://www.census.gov/foia
https://www.usa.gov/
https://www.census.gov//
123
```

Comment: @riya `comment` section is not for extend or reproduce your `code`. however the `len` without duplicates is `123`. you have to run the code on your end to check the output.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I was just showing you what I have. I'll try it out.

Comment: @riya no worries, I've seen your code on the question which you've asked. and verified your current output.

Comment: I tried it and got the same result and I take it its already in absolute format right? if not, is there anything I need to do to make it that.